# Problems on MatchQ[-3*i[1], -x_*i[1]]

Tags: pattern-matching

In my Mathematica 11.3.

```
MatchQ[-3*i[1], -x_*i[1]]
```

returns **False**.
But

```
MatchQ[-3*i[1], x_*i[1]]
```

returns **True**. I don't understand the reason. Does the minus "-" do something bad?

Comment: Yes, the `Minus` is the issue: `Head[-3]` is `Integer`, not `Minus`. But `Head[-x]` is `Minus`, so also `MatchQ[-3, -x_]` returns `False`.

Comment: In a situation like this the first thing to do is check the `FullForm` of the expression.

Comment: fyi, if you want to match negative coefficients you may try `MatchQ[-3*i[1], x_*i[1] /; x < 0]` (returns true)